# Delphi 2009 in-process com. Error message - 'Os function failed'

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have created an in-process com server using Delphi 7, it worked perfectly on windows XP and all windows pre-vista. After upgrading to windows vista, all interfaces are available except this only one interface that produces the following error message :

> 'Os function failed'.

Microsoft Developers Guide states that the Abstract Data Model has changed to cater for the 64-bits and 32-bits applications process interoperability. They introduced the helper functions and the new data types can be handled in the BaseTsd.h file which I can't find after installing CodeGear RAD Delphi 2009 Professional. Microsoft recommended importing of BaseTsd.tlb to take care of new Data Types on its latest Operating Systems that supports both 64-bits and 32-bits. If only could Delphi 2009 compiler could generate 64-bits app. I could at least get the warnings and error messages. I am having difficulties finding and generating BaseTsd.tlb file, where can I get one to import in my .ridl, please help.

Is there a workaround out there?

Sam

Comment: You will find BaseTsd.h in the Windows SDK, which is a free download from Microsoft. I doubt however that it will help you, as the interfaces should be binary compatible, and your in-process server is still 32 bit on Vista, so data type changes should not affect it. Would a permission problem not be a more likely explanation of the failure on Vista?

Comment: mghie, post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) to detect where the process got blocked and at least get a clue on what's happening.